# Rails, Nested Models, Arrays, Iterating through a "for" loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, models

I'm new to Ruby and following this novawave tutorial (a little older) on creating an internal messaging system.

http://www.novawave.net/public/rails_messaging_tutorial.html

I'm currently attempting to list the sent messages, but I am unable to properly link to the message "recipients."  Here is the for loop:

```
 <% for message in @messages %>
  <tr>
  <td><%= message.user.name %></td>

   <td><%= message.subject %></td>
   <td><%= message.recipients.map(&:user).to_sentence %></td>
```

I'm getting an "unitialized constant" error for "recipients"  I have three models: User, Message_Copy, and Message.

**Message Model**
belongs_to User,
has_many :recipients, :through => :message_copies

**Message_Copy model** 
belongs_to Message and recipient

**User model** 
has_many of the other models.

I've noticed this same problem in other applications.  When I iterate through the array, if the primary model "belongs to" another model, I can access that model.  For example, I can access the User model because the Message model "belongs_to" the User model.  Hence I can use message.user.name.  But I cannot access the attributes of a model that "belongs_to" the primary model.  So I cannot access the Message_Copy model attributes in this array.  So message.recipient.id will return an error.  This question may have already been answered, and I may just be making a series of easy mistakes.  But I'm confused and was hoping someone could help and possibly explain what I'm missing.  Please let me know if more informaiton is required.  Thank you

Apologies, here is more code from the models: 
**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :password
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => "Message"
has_many :received_messages, :class_name => "MessageCopy", :foreign_key =>"recipient_id"
has_many :folders

class MessageCopy < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :message
  belongs_to :recipient
  belongs_to :folder

delegate   :user, :created_at, :subject, :body, :recipients, :to => :message
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :user
 has_many :message_copies 
  has_many :recipients, :through => :message_copies
  before_create :prepare_copies

   attr_accessor  :to # array of people to send to
   attr_accessible :subject, :body, :to  

  def prepare_copies  
   return if to.blank?

     to.each do |recipient|
       recipient = User.find(recipient)
       @recipient=recipient
  message_copies.build(:recipient_id => recipient.id, :folder_id =>   recipient.inbox.id)
     end
   end    
 end
```

I noticed this worked: 
    <%= message.message_copies %>

Instead of the above code:

```
<td><%= message.recipients %></td>
```

I don't understand this because the tutorial can use "recipients" and also because I can reference the Message_Copy model through Recipients in other methods.

But 
    <%= message.message_copies %>
also just returns an array, and I'm unclear how I can reach the specific attributes in the message_copy model, since 
    <%= message.message_copies.content %>
does not work.

Thank you!  I'll post more code if necessary

Comment: Please post the code from your models.

Comment: Wow- two hours later I realize that I didn't include this line in the Message_Copy model ":class_name=>"User."  So it should've said- 
       belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => "User"

That's really frustrating.  I'm still not really sure what's going on, but at least it works.  I'll stare at it for another two hours in the hope that it starts making sense!

Comment: Basically it's saying to use the User model for recipient relationship. When you don't specify class_name it will attempt to infer the proper model, but in your case it couldn't figure out what model to use for the relationship, hence the error.

Comment: Thank you, I'm just new to rails and trying to get used to the structure.  Any info helps.